# POST form when fields are valid

Tags: jquery

I have form. when use submit the form I run jquery script that check validation. Is it possible to POST the form/page only if all the fields are valid?

Comment: Post some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` is what you need to stop form from submitting if it is not validated.

`validateForm()` function validates the form and returns true or false.
if it returns true then only form submits otherwise nothing happens.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform" action="abc.php" method="post">
<input type="text" />
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>

<script>

$("document").ready(function(e){
   
$("#myform").submit(function(e){

var test = validateForm();
if(test){
 $("#myform").submit();
}
else{
 e.preventDefault();
}

});

function validateForm()
{ 
 //after checking everything returns true or false
 return false;
}
    
});

</script>

</html>
```